# Which way is a better structure for users table in a shopping project - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012

I think it will be faster, but if its a better database design and structure I'm not sure,
Should I create a field in `Users` table which indicates if the user has a shopping cart or not, and only if its TRUE - 1 than to search for his `OrderID` in the `ShoppingCart` table ? 
Or just to search anyway for `OrderID` and `UserID` when the user is logging in ?

**Example**

```
[Users]
(
UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
EmailAddress NVARCHAR(320) UNIQUE,
PasswordHash VARCHAR(32),
FirstName VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
HasCart BIT DEFAULT 0
)

[ShoppingCart]
(
    OrderID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Users](UserID),
    CreatedDate DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)
```

Comment: Could you please add some more information? See this post here about creating a great example. https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You should put the UserID on the ShoppingCart, and index it.

```
create table ShoppingCart
(
    OrderID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID),
    INDEX ix_UserID (UserID),
    CreatedDate DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)
```

For old versions of SQL Server (2012 and before) you must create the index with a seperate statement:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_UserID on ShoppingCart(UserID)
```

This will support efficient lookups of ShoppingCart by UserID, and if you delete a User SQL Server won't have to scan ShoppingCart  to find that User's ShoppingCarts.

Comment: Hi and thanks, I searched and read about INDEX but didn't understand how will it be faster to search for userID  if exsist in the `ShoppingCart` table. I will be glad for some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create an additional column to indicate if the user has a cart for *performance reasons*, only do so if it makes logical sense to your use case.

It would actually be less performant (albeit likely negligible) to query the `Users` table first to then query the `ShoppingCart` table after, since it's two operations that would lock two tables to accomplish what could be done with one operation of always directly searching the `ShoppingCart` table.

As long as your `ShoppingCart` table is indexed on the fields that cover your search query (e.g. the OrderID if you're querying by that field), the performance (especially for only pulling one, or a small amount of records at a time) will be extremely quick. This is because indexes store the data logically in B-Tree data structures which has an **O(log(n))**.